# How to get the global variable inside the method

Tags: c#, oop

```
 class sample
 {
     public int i; //global variable
     public int[] arr = new int[10];
     public void fun(int i, int val)
     {
         Console.WriteLine(this.i); //I got Output is 11 
         arr[i] = val;
         Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
     }
 }

 class Program
 {
     static void Main(string[] args)
     {
         sample s = new sample();
         s.i = 1;
         s.fun(1, 7);
         Console.ReadLine();
     }
 }
```

How to get the global variable `i` inside the `fun()` method

> Here the function variable name and global variable name are the same.

Comment: Just use it without passing 'i' as a parameter of 'fun'

Comment: Try `this.i` if you want `i` field. Note that `i` is not a global variable but a field

Comment: That's not a global variable, there's no such thing in C#. And you're looking for `this.i`, perhaps?

Comment: I recommend to avoid having the same name for a field and a parameter. Even though you can disambiguate by using `this.` for the field, it is confusing to read.

Comment: Am trying to get `this.i` but I got `11`. I can't understand the code flow please explain

Comment: When I run your code, I get two lines: "1" and "7", as expected.

Comment: As Klaus said, it returns 1 and 7 as expected. See [here(DotNetFiddle)](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SUSIeI).

Answer (score 2):

To access the field `i` within the `fun()` method, you can use the `this` keyword. For example:

```
class sample
{
    public int i; //global variable
    public int[] arr = new int[10];
    public void fun(int i, int val)
    {
        this.i = i; // assign the value of the function parameter to the field
        arr[i] = val;
        Console.WriteLine(arr[i]);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you can also use a different name for the function parameter to avoid the naming conflict. For example:

```
class sample
{
    public int i; // field
    public int[] arr = new int[10];
    public void fun(int j, int val)
    {
        i = j; // assign the value of the function parameter to the field
        arr[j] = val;
        Console.WriteLine(arr[j]);
    }
}
```